# Xamarin Webview Wont Launch New Tabs

Tags: android, xamarin, webview

I was playing with xamarin android webview and i encountered this problem.The webview does not open the pages that is set to open in new tab. For example there are job advertisements on stackoverflow that are set to open in new tabs and when you touch on them nothing happens!. Thanks in the advance and here is my code.

```
 [Activity(MainLauncher = false, Theme = "@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar")]
public class Obs_Activity : Activity
{
    WebView web_view;
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.sist);
        web_view = FindViewById<WebView>(Resource.Id.webview);
        web_view.Settings.SetSupportMultipleWindows(false);
        web_view.Settings.UseWebViewBackgroundForOverscrollBackground = true;
        web_view.Settings.PluginsEnabled = true;
        web_view.Settings.AllowFileAccess = true;
        web_view.Settings.DisplayZoomControls = true;
        web_view.SetWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient(this));


        web_view.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
        web_view.Settings.JavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically = true;
        web_view.Settings.SetSupportZoom(true);
        web_view.LoadUrl("http://obs.kku.edu.tr/");
    }




}
public class HelloWebViewClient : WebViewClient
{
    public Activity mActivity;
    public HelloWebViewClient(Activity mActivity)
    {
        this.mActivity = mActivity;
    }
    public override bool ShouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, string url)
    {
        view.LoadUrl(url);
        Toast.MakeText(mActivity, "Yukleniyor...",
                             ToastLength.Long).Show();
        return true;
    }

    public override void OnReceivedHttpAuthRequest(WebView view, HttpAuthHandler handler, string host, string realm)
    {
        base.OnReceivedHttpAuthRequest(view, handler, host, realm);
        Toast.MakeText(mActivity, "Hata", ToastLength.Long).Show();
    }
}
```

> 01-23 13:02:36.695 D/WebViewCallback(16789): shouldInterceptRequest=http://ogrenciportal.kku.edu.tr/getinfo.ashx?id=3&tt=690
>   01-23 13:02:36.711 D/WebViewCallback(16789): onLoadResource=http://ogrenciportal.kku.edu.tr/getinfo.ashx?id=3&tt=690
>   01-23 13:02:36.712 D/WebViewCallback(16789): doUpdateVisitedHistory=http://ogrenciportal.kku.edu.tr/Default.aspx# reload=false
>   01-23 13:02:36.740 D/WebViewCallback(16789): onPageFinished, url = http://ogrenciportal.kku.edu.tr/Default.aspx#

This is the log when i press that link and nothing happens.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to open links in new tab android webview?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38034769/how-to-open-links-in-new-tab-android-webview)

Comment: Nope its not even close.

Answer (score 0):

WebView does not support *tabs* if you want a tabbed browser UI you need to implement it yourself.

You are setting `SetSupportMultipleWindows` to `true`, but not implementing `WebChromeClient` and it's `OnCreateWindow` method.

> Sets whether the WebView whether supports multiple windows. If set to true, onCreateWindow(WebView, boolean, boolean, Message) must be implemented by the host application.

- If you want the `Apply Now` / JavaScript popups to appear in a **new page**, continue using `WebViewClient` but set `SetSupportMultipleWindows` to **`false`**.
- If you want to open a new `WebView` in a tab, you need to implement a `WebChromeClient` subclass and override the `OnWindowCreate` and set it via `WebView.SetWebChromeClient` otherwise the link will be opened in the default|system web browser.

Comment: I dont want a tabbed browser i just want to display the new tabs as they are not a new tab , in the same webview. I set SetSupportMultipleWindows to false still when you click some link that is set to new tab nothing happens.

Comment: Okay new tabs are fine just as i wanted on the webview. The browser blocks the new tab. Thats the issue here i think. Editted the main post.

Comment: I set setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically to true. Now a new blank page opens. Why it is blank, weird

Comment: When you cilck to that link on google chrome it says google chrome blocked a pop-up window. I think thats the issue here

Comment: @M.Han Set `SetSupportMultipleWindows` to false if you are not implementing a `WebChromeClient`, it will open in a new page (does on my `WebView`).

Comment: I did set it to false. I also set setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically to true. There is action now but the page is blank. I suspect it might be about the popup window block because the page gets blocked when i click to link on google chrome too.

Comment: @M.Han Strange as I can open those links just fine (Note: only tested in API 23 & 24 using `WebView` versions 44.0.2403.119 through 55.0.2883.91.

Comment: Just to make sure, you can open the links that gets blocked by browsers? Like when im on my computer when i click that link on chrome it shows me "popup window blocked you want to allow?" something like that. And when i click the exact same link on webview just a blank page appears.

Comment: Using your code, yes a blank page appears for links like "apply now" that are "popups" (javascript-based actually), but not using MultipleWindows that link will open in a new page, or using WebChromeClient/OnWindowCreate, I can create a smaller WebView that overlays the original WebView like a popup and display the page (only really useful on larger screens : ie. tablets)

Comment: I editted my code. Still blank page appears. Multiplewindows is set to false. Do i need to override the OnWindowCreate method?