# Need to display browser kind of webview(open external links as a tabs) in android

Tags: android, browser, tabs, android-webview

[image]I have a requirement to display webview in android application and if user click on any links on webview screen it should be open in a tabs(like same as chrome browser). So user can switch any of the tabs and view the results. Is it possible to navigate browser kind of tabs in android webview?

For Ex Im open some portal link in android webview [enter link description here](https://www.irctc.co.in/nget/train-search) and I tried to open PNR status/ vacancy on that protal. For this i need to show PNR/vacancy are like a tabs not to add screens on top it.

Please suggest how to achieve this requirement

Thanks you

Comment: You are saying you want to show a link into webview or whats your point ?

Answer (score 0):

For displaying `webview` you need to define in the `xml` at first.
Second you need in `java` something like this.
The first is the `XML`. Second is how you need to define in `java`

```
<WebView
   android:id="@+id/webView"
   android:background="@color/downloadText"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"/>


private WebView webView;
webView = findViewById(R.id.webView);
webView.loadUrl("https://www.google.com");


webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {

@Override
public boolean onCreateWindow(WebView view, boolean isDialog,
        boolean isUserGesture, Message resultMsg) {

        WebView newWebView = new WebView(WebViewActivity2.this);
        view.addView(newWebView);
        WebView.WebViewTransport transport = (WebView.WebViewTransport) resultMsg.obj;
        transport.setWebView(newWebView);
        resultMsg.sendToTarget();

        newWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                browserIntent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
                startActivity(browserIntent);
                return true;
            }
        });
    return true;

    });
```

Comment: Thanks for your response

Comment: We are here to help you anything you want :), if this helped you make as accepted.

Comment: I am expecting if user load any url in webview and click on any link on that it should be open in a tab.  For Example 
Load url in webview[Irctc](https://www.irctc.co.in/nget/train-search) and click on PNR status or charts/vacancy. These are open like a tabs, please check the link.

I need same like browser feel in android webview.

Comment: I checked your code, user click on any of the link it loads on top of the webview screen. If we want to see the main webview screen we have to come back and see it.  I checked this link using java script we can acheive this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38034769/how-to-open-links-in-new-tab-android-webview

Im thinking to implement this functionality I need to customize to add tabs in dynamically and remove it dynamically.  
Like first, I need to load webview in single tab
Any click is happend on webview we dynamically load sub webview in another tab